Teradata - Get unique values among the column in a row
How to obtain unique values from a set of columns for each row in a table.
Consider the following table structure:
COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4
--------------------------
  1  |  1   |  2   |  3
  2  |  2   |  2   |  4
  4  |  5   |  6   |  7

The desired result should look like this:
COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4
--------------------------
  1  |  2   |  3   | NULL
  2  |  4   | NULL | NULL
  4  |  5   |  6   |  7

I was able to achieve this by case statements by comparing each columns with each other. Are there any other way to do this?

Having to remove duplicates and fill up with nulls in the rows suggests that the data model is inappropriate. Probably, you should rather have a table holding the values in rows instead of columns. Then such problems would not arise.

You could use UNPIVOT (or UNION) + PIVOT
UNPIVOT - Get a row for each value of colN
Rank them and get the distinct.
PIVOT back to the original column list.
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE some_data
(
    COL1 INTEGER,
    COL2 INTEGER,
    COL3 INTEGER,
    COL4 INTEGER
) 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO some_data (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4) VALUES (1, 1, 2, 3);
INSERT INTO some_data (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4) VALUES (2, 2, 2, 4);
INSERT INTO some_data (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4) VALUES (4, 5, 6, 7);

with 
add_a_key as (
    select row_number() over ( order by 1) as a_key,
           sd.*
      from some_data sd),
unpivot_ranked as (
    select distinct
           a_key,
           val,
           dense_rank() over ( 
             partition by a_key
                 order by val ) as rn
      from add_a_key
      unpivot (
           val 
           for col in (col1, col2, col3, col4)
    ) as unpivoted
)
select col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       col4
  from unpivot_ranked
 pivot (
       sum(val) for rn in (1 as col1 ,
                           2 as col2,
                           3 as col3,
                           4 as col4)
       ) t
 order
    by col1;




COL1
COL2
COL3
COL4




1
2
3
?


2
4
?
?


4
5
6
7



